# Show that the innerproduct of two vector is a differentiable mapping

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question is to show that the innerproduct is a differentiable mapping.
Define $g: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $ g(x_1,x_2) = <x_1|x_2>$. We use the productmetric on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. Now we have to show that $g$ is differentiable in every point $(a_1,a_2) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and that the total derivative in every point is given by:

$
Dg(a_1,a_2)(h_1,h_2) = <a_1|h_2> + <h_1|a_2>, \, h_1,h_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$

The productmetric is defined as $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = d(x_1,y_1) + d(x_2,y_2)$.

And using the formula for differentiation:
$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \|f(a+h) - f(a) - Df(a)(h) \|}{\|h\|} = 0$

Plugging in $g$ for $f$ I figured that

$g(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2) - g(a_1,a_2)=\,  <a_1+h_1 | a_2+h_2> - <a_1|a_2> = \, <a_1|h_2> + <h_1|a_2> + <h_1 | h_2>. $

This is the point where I'm stuck. How can I come from here to concluding $Dg(a_1,a_2)(h_1,h_2) = <a_1|h_2> + <h_1|a_2>$? And where do I use the productmetric?